# number of threads/worker spawned

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker

I am trying to work with a worker but I am getting the system crashed so I believe the issue is because multiple event handlers are spawning threads without waiting for others to get killed.

Is there any way I can check how many threads are spawned at the moment so that i can check and debug the system?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: In Chrome's devtools, if you go to the "sources" tab, and look at the "page" tab on the left, you will see a list of all workers that are running (the workers have a gear icon to their left). To be able to better identify individual workers in this list, you can supply a `name` parameter to the options object, e.g. `new Worker(url, {name: "MyWorker"})` will show `MyWorker` in the devtools. This may be helpful in determining what part of the code is responsible for spawning the workers.